# Which Apple Watch Faces Support Modular Large Complications

Tags: apple-watch, watchos

I've been searching everywhere for this and I can't find it anywhere. I'm learning how to develop WatchOS apps.

In the tutorial I'm working with they're working on building a Modular Large Complication.

I found that the Siri watch face supports Modular Small complications (the only watch face I could find supporting that).

Unfortunately after extensive searching I can't find a watch face on my Series 5 Apple Watch with Watch OS version 6.1 that supports a modular large complication.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Start by referring to the Complications sections in the Apple's official watchOS Human Interface Guidelines:

- [Modular Large - Complications - App Architecture - watchOS - Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/watchos/app-architecture/complications#modular-large)

> #### Modular Large
>
> These templates offer a large canvas for displaying up to three rows of content (for example, in the center of the Modular watch face).
>
> [image]

Now if you look through the Watch Faces as available in watchOS 6.1, the following Watch Faces support displaying Modular Large Complications:

1. Infograph Modular

   [image]
2. Modular

   [image]
3. Modular Compact

   [image]